# Allow an action once per session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I have a site that tracks video views... every time the controller is called. One could flood their own video views with some heavy F5ing.

How to make it so a view counts or a method runs only once per session?

```
def show
  new_views = @video.views + 1
  @video.update_attributes(:views => new_views)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a session variable, probably upon login, like :

```
session[:is_logged] = 1
```

Then, every time you are about to increment the counter, just check this variable.

Comment: Went back to this, and actually had to assign an array to get this to work containing each video ID. for those who care...

Answer (score 2):

Single session variable doesn't work because you have many videos and you would like to separate counts for different videos. I think that a better way is to store view events in db.

- pros: you can even allow action once
  per user avoiding login/logout
- cons: huge size of users_videos table

Answer (score 0):

Well the simplest way would be to track it in the session itself:

```
def show
  if session[:has_counted_view] == nil
    new_views = @video.views + 1
    @video.update_attributes(:views => new_views)
    session[:has_counted_view] = true
  end
end
```